# The objective is not DCP

Tags: cvxpy, convex-optimization

I try to solve the convex problem on page 20 presented in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224594070_Time-Optimal_Path_Tracking_for_Robots_A_Convex_Optimization_Approach)

[image]

In my opinion, the objective is convex.

cvxpy version 1.1.18

prob is DCP: False

it reports

> xception has occurred: DCPError Problem does not follow DCP rules.
> Specifically: The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions
> are not:
> 0.004 / (power(var1[0], 0.5) + power(var1[0], 0.5))
> 0.004 / (power(var1[1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224594070_Time-Optimal_Path_Tracking_for_Robots_A_Convex_Optimization_Approach), 0.5) + power(var1[1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224594070_Time-Optimal_Path_Tracking_for_Robots_A_Convex_Optimization_Approach), 0.5))

[image]

my code is

```
K = 1000
KK = 500
delta = 1/(1000)*2
a = cp.Variable(KK)
b = cp.Variable(KK+1,nonneg=True)
tau = cp.Variable((KK,7))
print('create problem')
print('cvx version')
print(cp.__version__)
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cp.sum([2*delta/(cp.sqrt(b[i])+cp.sqrt(b[i+1])) for i in range(KK)])),
          [...])
```

a concise example reports the same problem

```
import copy as cp

# A non-DCP problem.
K=5
x=cp.Variable(K+1)
prob = cp.Problem(\
    cp.Minimize( cp.sum([1/(cp.sqrt(x[i]) +cp.sqrt(x[i+1])) for i in range(K)]) )\
        ,[x>=25,x<=100])
print( "prob is DCP:", prob.is_dcp())
print('be solving  by cvxpy')
try:
    prob.solve()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cp.inv_pos(u)` instead of `1/u`.

Comment: Thanks for contributing! If you find time please edit an explanation into the answer as it's recommended to [explain entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421) on StackOverflow.